# Foreign Keys constraint is not working in SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I am dropping pk from table 1 to table 2 as foreign key in my database using sqlite. But my table 2 is not working accordingly to foreign key constraint it is inserting record if that key is not available in table1. I am using db browser and my pragma foreign key is enabled there but its still  not working

[image: I have attached its image]

Comment: When I try to insert data using Db browser then foreign key constraint is working properly, the issue occurs when I try to insert data through c# form

Comment: So have you enabled foreign keys in your C# code?

Comment: To elaborate, every single time you open a sqlite database you have to enable foreign key support with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`. See https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable for details. It's not a persistent setting.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. You have to enable pragma foreign keys in your C# code everytime you make a connection.
Let me share my code:

```
 conn.Open();
            string query = " insert into Installment_Details (Account_No,Month_yr,Date,Receipt_No,Amount_Received,Amount_Left,Amount_receiver) values ('" + this.Textbox_AN.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_MY.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_D.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_RN.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_AR.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_AL.Text + "','" + this.Textbox_ARR.Text + "');";
            SQLiteCommand createcommand = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", conn);
            createcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            createcommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
            createcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to turn the pragma on in here:

```
SQLiteCommand createcommand = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", conn);
```

but better to turn it on when the connection is created:

```
ConnectionString = $"Data Source={databaseFile}; foreign keys=true";
connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
```

and then create the command and call the ExecuteNonQuery().